# What is lower contour

Tags: image, image-processing, contour

I'm reading a research paper where it says, **The segmenting points occur at the lower contour of the strokes in a word.** I've searched the internet but I don't find anything useful for **lower contour**.

Comment: What paper is that?

Comment: I don't know if it's a standard term, I've never heard it before, but it might refer to the bottom part of the contour.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You don't say :p

Comment: @Ash: I figured out how to use a thesaurus.